# NSString to fixed length char array conversion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, arrays

I am having a struct which contains a char array like this:

```
char name[10];
```

Now I need a way to convert NSString to this type of string.

I already can convert this string to a NSString:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:name length:10      
encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` method of `NSString`:

```
char name[10];
NSString *s = @"Hello";
[s getCString:name maxLength:10 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is how I now convert an NSString to the char array:
`char name[10];
NSString* str = @"John";
[str getCString:name maxLength:10 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
`

And this is converting from a char array to NSString
`NSString* stringB = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**the full conversion process** back and forth:

```
// from NSString through char* to NSString again
NSString *text = @"long text or short";
const char *constName = [text UTF8String];

char *name = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * text.length + 1);
memcpy(name, constName, sizeof(unichar) * text.length);

NSString *fromChar = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];

NSLog(@"%@", fromChar);

free(name);
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I can't use any pointers in this case.

Comment: how do you mean _you can't use any pointer_? **you are already using pointers** when you define the `char name[10];` it is very similar to the `char *name;` and `name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);` lines. could you clarify your comment, maybe?

Comment: OK, the string is part of a struct which is allocated as an array. When there are no pointers in the struct I can save the whole array to the disk by just copying the bytes directly out of the memory. With pointers this would not be this simple, especially with several pointers. Thanks for your effort anyways.